# How to calculate the variance of a discrete signal?

Tags: matlab

Explained as:
'the variance of the signal is the mean of its squares minus the square of its mean'

The mean of its squares (average of instantaneous power of all samples) minus the square of its mean (all samples added together and squared).

$$
\sigma (x) \equiv E[x^2] - (E[x])^2
$$

Im not sure if my script correct? 
And what is E in the equations for variance?

```
%% 
clc 
clear

%% Signal
x = [ 0  5  5  0 -5 -5 ];
fs = 6;

%% Power Calculations

% Instantaneous power of each sample:
ins_pwr = x .^ 2;
disp(['Instantaneous Power (w) = ' mat2str(ins_pwr)]);

% Average power of signal:
avg_pwr = sum(ins_pwr)/length(x);
disp(['Average power (w) = ' num2str(avg_pwr)]);

% Variance of the signal:
var_pwr = (sum(ins_pwr)/length(x)) - (sum(x)^2);
disp(['Variance (w) = ' num2str(var_pwr)]);
```

Output:

- Instantaneous Power (w) = [0 25 25 0 25 25]
- Average power (w) = 16.6667
- Variance (w) = 16.6667

Comment: Please see here: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10620/algorithm-to-compute-the-variance-of-the-signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is E in the equations for variance?**

\$E\$ means "the expected value of something", please refer to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value

And as you've said

> 'the variance of the signal is the mean of its squares minus ***the
>   square of its mean***'

So

> var_pwr = (sum(ins_pwr)/length(x)) -
>   (sum(x)^2);

should be

> var_pwr = sum(ins_pwr)/length(x) - (sum(x) / length(x))^2;

And there is another method to get signal's variance, you can see **Ref. 1** and **Ref. 3**.

**Some references:**

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value
3. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10620/algorithm-to-compute-the-variance-of-the-signal